# Defining a fixed Width and Height for a JavaScript dialog, is it a bad practice

Tags: css, layout

Hi I am working inside SharePoint 2013, and I have added the following code to display a pop-up window:-

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://www.test.net', 1200,1200);" unselectable="on">TWeb Site</a>
```

First of all If I do not specify a Width and height the dialog will be small, so I manually define 1200 for highly and width.

Now on my development machine the pop-up showed well  , where the current resolution is (1920 1080). But will my pop-up worked well if the user have higher or lower screen resolution ? And what is the best way to make sure that the pop-up is displayed well inside different screen resolutions?
Thanks

Comment: You should just use a `target="_blank"` and let the browser decide... Chances are the user will want it to load in a new tab anyways.

Comment: why i should define "target=_black". i need the popup to show a site and the requirment was that i need to display a pop-up window.